# Interfacing Octave and Lazarus/FreePascal with TProcess

Tags: delphi, octave, lazarus, freepascal

[I have also asked this question @ the Lazarus forums, here](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,35823.msg237734.html#msg237734)

I am trying to communicate with Octave via a TProcess, but I don't seem to be able to read any bytes from it. Attached is the main form's unit; a full demo application is available as a zip from the forum under my post.

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Process;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  POctave: TProcess;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (not POctave.Running) then
  begin
    POctave.Executable := 'C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.0\bin\octave-cli.exe';
    POctave.Parameters.Add('--no-gui');
    POctave.Options := [poUsePipes];
    WriteLn('-- Executing octave --');
    POctave.Execute;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  command: string;
  Buffer: string;
  BytesAvailable: DWord;
  BytesRead: longint;
  NoMoreOutput: boolean;
begin
  command := 'pwd' + #10;
  if (POctave.Running) then
    POctave.Input.Write(command, Length(command));

  if (POctave.Running) then
  begin
    BytesAvailable := POctave.Output.NumBytesAvailable;
    BytesRead := 0;
    while BytesAvailable > 0 do
    begin
      SetLength(Buffer, BytesAvailable);
      BytesRead := POctave.OutPut.Read(Buffer[1], BytesAvailable);
      WriteLn(Buffer);
      BytesAvailable := POctave.Output.NumBytesAvailable;
      NoMoreOutput := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

initialization
  POctave := TProcess.Create(nil);

finalization
  POctave.Free;

end.
```

I've added sleep routines and changed the 'pwd' command's return to #1310, both without success.

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  command: ansistring;
  Buffer: string;
  BytesAvailable: DWord;
  BytesRead: longint;
  NoMoreOutput: boolean;
begin
  command := 'pwd'#13#10;
  if (POctave.Running) then
    POctave.Input.Write(command, Length(command));
  Sleep(100);

  if (POctave.Running) then
begin
    Sleep(100);
    BytesAvailable := POctave.Output.NumBytesAvailable;
    BytesRead := 0;
    while BytesAvailable > 0 do
    begin
      Sleep(100);
      SetLength(Buffer, BytesAvailable);
      BytesRead := POctave.OutPut.Read(Buffer[1], BytesAvailable);
      WriteLn(Buffer);
      BytesAvailable := POctave.Output.NumBytesAvailable;
      NoMoreOutput := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: you immediately abort when no bytes are available and octave is not the speediest of programs.

Comment: I've tried to add sleep too the routines to allow for a delay with no success, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you run 'octave --eval 1+1' ? POctave.Parameters.Add('--eval');POctave.Parameters.Add('1+1'); And btw: what do you really want to archive? Controle Octave via pipes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was calling this line:

```
POctave.Input.Write(command, Length(command));
```

instead of this:

```
POctave.Input.Write(command[1], Length(command));
```

After changing this (AND ADDING THE DELAY! It was absolutely critical to wait for the result, but my mistake was more fundamental.)

Remember: Pascal strings aren't C strings. Whoops...

It worked! Now I can send commands to Octave and retrieve the results via pipes. :)

Comment: Don't use Sleep(...). Instead, add poWaitOnExit to the Options of TProcess (see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#TProcess)

Comment: I'm actually going to be dumping some rather large matrices out of Octave; if I use poWaitOnExit and the buffer fills up, it can lead to a deadlock.